# Using MYSQL ORDER BY clause, is it possible to ORDER BY some field in a custom order

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have this column called `code` that look like : `1-100-ETC-60`,`1-100-ETC-20`,`1-100-ETC-70`

The last two characters are always going to start with either 6, 2 or 7.

If I do a ORDER BY SUBSTRING(code,13) ASC, or DESC it's going to sort them in numerical order. Thought that's not what I want (or the client want).

The correct sorting order should be : 6 then 2 then 7.

Just want to know if this is possible solely through the use of SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```sql
ORDER BY FIELD(SUBSTRING(code, 11, 1), '6', '2', '7')
```

Comment: you would want to add  ",SUBSTRING(code,12)" to that to get the rest of the code in proper order if it includes 60, 61, 62 etc, correct?

Comment: that's what I did. worked well. thanks. This one is also a bit shorter than the CASE method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement.

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(code,11) = '6' THEN '1' + substring(code, 12) ELSE SUBSTRING(code,11) END
```

should convert the 6 to a one for sorting with the 2 and the 7 in this case

(Substring is 1 indexed in mysql, so it's 11, not 10)

Comment: great! thanks.. it works. I'm wondering does this slow down the query significantly?

Comment: I can't speak for mysql but I know in SQL server it adds a step to the execution plan. It however does not look like it affects it too much, the order by is still going to take up more power. You could try running both queries with Explain and see what the result is for your data.